# How to stop discord bot respond to itself/all other bots [Discord Bot in Python 3.6]

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am very new to programming and just learning. I figured making a discord bot is a good way to learn and I'm enjoying it, I'm just a little stuck. So my bot is private and there's a running joke in our discord server that whenever a user sends "k" all bots respond with "k". ATM we have Dyno, my friend's private bot and hopefully mine. I got all my code working except because the command and the answer is the same my bot just spams the server with "k" until I shut down the bot, how do I stop it?

**The code:**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content ==("k"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "k")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Sounds like a logical problem to me.  Your bot sends `k`.  This message arrives at your bot itself again, is interpreted as another trigger, so your bot sends `k` *again*, thus closing an endless loop.  How about (for now) let your bot react ok `x` only and reply with `k`?  Then it cannot trigger itself.  The proper solution would be to look at the triggering message more closely and if it can be found out that it was a message from the bot itself, ignore it.

Comment: You need to add either a test to check the username of the entity that posted "K" or... You need to add a time out before being able to respond again, say 5 seconds

Comment: I do have a temporary workaround for now that it responds with k! so it sn't infinite but it stills repeats is like two or three times. I'll look more into how to ignore certain user ie itself and all other bots. Its not much, but it's  start :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is ok, I finally figured it out. To those having the same issue you have to add

```
if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
```

to the code and it works so mine looks like this now:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content.startswith('k'):
        msg = 'k'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run this on your message event:

```js
if(!message.author.user.bot) return; //not the exact code
```

Because the message event can `return` the user, and the user has a default [bot check](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.bot). `message.author` returns a member, so you can call the `user` object of [member](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author) and then perform the check as I did above.

**Pseudocode:**

```
If the author of the message (user) is a bot: return; 
This will prevent an infinite loop from occuring
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this in js-->

```
 if (message.author.bot == false){
  //code here if the user isn't a bot
 }
//lol i am noob yet
```